# getting only first <li> of <ul>

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is the problem. I have a websites and few subpages

subpages:
DAMSKIE,
MĘSKIE,
DZIECIĘCE,
SPORT,
AKCESORIA,
PREMIUM,
TOREBKI,
WYPRZEDAŻ,

On each of it are few categorizing elemens like "Półbuty", "Klapki" etc.

I can get Subpages but i can't get the list of categorizing elements (Półbuty, Klapki etc). If list looks like: "Półbuty", "Klapki", "Obcasy" my code gets only "Półbuty", but he doesn't get "Klapki" or "Obcasy".

[Image of subpages+the list of elements im trying to get][1]

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Crawler_Shoes
{
    public class Crawl
    {
        private static string navBar = "megamenu__item";
        private const string shoesTypes = "sidebar-section__wrapper sidebar-section__wrapper--categories";
        private static string mainSite = "https://www.eobuwie.com.pl/";
        public static List<string> categoriesNames = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> linksNames = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> categoriesOfCategoriesNames = new List<string>();
        private readonly List<Shoes> shoes = new List<Shoes>();

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<HtmlNode>> HttpClient(string site, string descendant, string equals)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(site);
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
            return htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants(descendant)
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals(equals)).ToList();
        }
        public static async Task GetCategories()
        {
            var menu = await HttpClient(mainSite, "li", navBar);                      
            foreach (var nav in menu)
            {
                //links.Add(nav.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                categoriesNames.Add(nav.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().InnerText); //gets names of categories
                linksNames.Add(nav.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value); //gets links for categories
                if(categoriesNames.Last() == "\n\t\t\tWyprzedaż\t\t")
                {
                    categoriesNames.Remove(categoriesNames.Last());
                    linksNames.Remove(categoriesNames.Last());
                }
            }
            Crawl.GetCategoriesofCategories();
        }
        public static async Task GetCategoriesofCategories()
        {
                for (var i = 0; i <= categoriesNames.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    var categories = await HttpClient(linksNames.ElementAt(i), "ul", shoesTypes);
                    categoriesOfCategoriesNames.Add(categoriesNames.ElementAt(i));
                    foreach(var li in categories)
                    {
                        categoriesOfCategoriesNames.Add(li.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

The part with the problem:

```
    public static async Task GetCategoriesofCategories()
            {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= categoriesNames.Count-1; i++)
                    {
                        var categories = await HttpClient(linksNames.ElementAt(i), "ul", shoes

Types);
                    categoriesOfCategoriesNames.Add(categoriesNames.ElementAt(i));
                    foreach(var li in categories)
                    {
                        categoriesOfCategoriesNames.Add(li.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value);
                    }
                }

        }
```

Comment: As a side issue, `HttpClient` is not a great method name (since it is also a type). It makes the code hard to understand.

Comment: Why not using AgilityPack for loading the html page directly from the web?

Comment: I can tell you how to get those categories but if you want to know why your code doesn't work, that depends on what values are taking "descendant", "equals", "categoriesNames". You're not providing information for reproducing the problem so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Alright i will just get whole code into snipper

Answer (score 1):

I had success with this:

```
string url = "https://www.eobuwie.com.pl/damskie.html";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
var sidebar = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='sidebar-section__wrapper sidebar-section__wrapper--categories']");
var categories = sidebar.SelectNodes("li");
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    var anchor = category.SelectSingleNode("a");
    string shoeCategory = anchor.InnerText.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(shoeCategory);
}
```

It's a bit different than how you're doing it, but I at least hope you'll be able to take some hints from this and apply it to your own code.

If you need the links as well, add this:

```
string shoeCategoryLink = anchor.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
```

Comment: That's nice and it's works, but i would like to take your code (from string url to var categories) into function (like in my example). I'm trying to move it to function but it just doesn't work then. Could you help me with that too please?

Comment: I can't seem to get your code to work for me. In the `GetCategoriesofCategories()` method, change the `foreach` loop to display the `innerHtml` of `li`. Is the html all the same?

Comment: After change it works the same. It displays:
"\n\t\t\tDamskie\t\t"
"\n                        Półbuty                    "
"\n\t\t\tMęskie\t\t"
"\n                        Klapki i sandały                    ".

So it displays the first <li> of every next subpage and it doesn't display whole list of <li>.

Comment: If the cod doesn't work get rid of shoes list. In program.cs write Crawl.GetCategories();   and that's it. The code works when you get Damskie and Męskie but doesn't work for categories like Sandały Półbuty etc